# How to solve the Invalid Index in Terraform?

Tags: dns, terraform

When I try to add a PTR record in DNS, I get this error with Invalid index. I am uncertain how to remove the error.

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "app-stage" {
  count             = length(var.datacenter)
  name              = "app-stage-${var.datacenter[count.index]}.example.com"
  flavor_name       = var.flavor["app-stage"]
  availability_zone = element(var.datacenter, count.index)
  key_pair          = var.key_pair
  image_id          = var.os_image
  config_drive      = true
  user_data         = data.template_file.app-stage[count.index].rendered
  scheduler_hints {
    group = openstack_compute_servergroup_v2.app_sg.id
  }
  network {
    port = openstack_networking_port_v2.app-stage[count.index].id
  }
}

resource "dns_aaaa_record_set" "app-stage-dns" {
  count     = length(var.datacenter)
  zone      = format("%s.", var.dns_zone)
  name      = "app-stage-${var.datacenter[count.index]}.example"
  addresses = [replace(openstack_compute_instance_v2.app-stage[count.index].access_ip_v6, "/\\[|\\]/", "")]
  ttl       = 300
}

resource "dns_ptr_record" "app-stage-dns-ptr" {
  count = length(var.datacenter)
  zone  = format("%s.", var.dns_ptr_zone)
  ptr   = "app-stage-${var.datacenter[count.index]}.example"
  name  = tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns)[count.index].addresses[0]
  ttl   = 300
```

This is the error-messages i get when running terraform apply,:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on app-stage.tf line 94, in resource "dns_ptr_record" "app-stage-dns-ptr":
  94:   name  = tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns)[count.index].addresses[0]
    |----------------
    | count.index is 1
    | dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns is tuple with 2 elements

This value does not have any indices.
```

This is repeated 2 times, since I try to create 2 machines/2records.

Comment: Have you tried with `tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns[count.index].addresses)[0]` - closing parenthesis  in different place?

Comment: Yes, just saw it, thanks! Comment it as a solution, and I will give you credit for it :D

Comment: Thanks. Answer provided :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

It should be:

```
name  = tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns[count.index].addresses)[0]
```

not (closing parenthesis in different place)

```
name  = tolist(dns_aaaa_record_set.app-stage-dns)[count.index].addresses[0]
```